# Lifecycle Hooks in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Wijmo grid in my application. But the grid does not appear properly on the screen initially.
The first column is a checkbox one, and that method calls this.flex.refresh, which actually refreshes and maybe re-renders the grid.

So initially when the page is loaded only one cell with a checkbox is displayed. When I click on it, the full grid is displayed.
If I remove the flex refresh method from the call then it displays everything.

My assumption is that the CSS of the grid is not loaded before the actual grid is rendered. (although it should since I have it in my angular-CLI JSON).

So, what I am trying to do is do a refresh when the page is loaded completely but i cannot find a reliable hook.

The flex variable is assigned its value once everything is completed.(it comes as undefined in constructor or ngInit).

So, I am trying to find a reliable hook where it will be present.

I tried ngAfterViewInit,ngAfterContentInit but it is undefined there.

If i do

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.flex.refresh();
    }, 500);
  }
```

Then it sometimes works and sometimes does not. in setTimeout i can find the flex variable most of the times and sometimes not. So this seems a bit unreliable.
I was wondering if there is a hook where I can call the method. A hook which would be invoked after the page is completely initialized.
AfterViewInit & afterContentInit seem to be invoked after the initialization has started and not completed.

Comment: how do you add your `Wijmo` grid into the page and Angular application?

Answer (score 0):

You may call the same in `ngAfterViewChecked()`. As the documentation states this is called when:

```
Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.

Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().
```

Comment: If I do that, then i get alot of errors.I am consoling after everything this.flex

After Everything  undefined
ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
After Everything  [object Object]
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'undefined'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation, last hook is a `ngAfterViewChecked`.
However u need to close look this:

> Angular throws an error if the hook updates the component's data-bound comment property immediately (try it!). The LoggerService.tick_then() postpones the log update for one turn of the browser's JavaScript cycle and that's just long enough.

[wait a tick](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#wait-a-tick)

Comment: If I do that, then i get alot of errors.I am consoling after everything this.flex

After Everything  undefined
ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'refresh' of undefined or null reference
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
After Everything  [object Object]
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'undefined'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook?

Comment: u get this error coz u register fn in stack and for example u change a page, the scope has changed

Comment: "Has it been created in a change detection hook?" use this: `changeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` here u are a doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html

Comment: It seems ngAfterViewChecked is called after every change detection. the refresh method might be changing something internally. Not sure how to proceed on this.

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri can u provide a plunker ? it's be easier to help you

Comment: Unfortunately I may not be able to provide a plunker as the components I use are licensed and wouldn't be available through their CDN.